# Unable to create AKS cluster on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I was trying to create an AKS cluster and it failed with the following message in the portal

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
        "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
        "details": [
            {
                "code": "ReconcileStandardLoadBalancerError",
                "message": "Reconcile standard load balancer failed. Details: standardLoadBalancerReconciler retry failed: Code=\"SubscriptionNotRegistered\" Message=\"Subscription xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is not registered with NRP.\" Details=[]."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create the AKS cluster? Provide more details.

Comment: In the "Resource Provider" section of your Subscription. Make sure you have to register the failing object type there.

Answer (score 3):

you have to go into All services -> Subscriptions -> Resource providers

And get this registered.

**Microsoft.Kubernetes Registered**